# FancyBox - Arrows/Navigation using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

In [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/RYXOeK?editors=1000) I have 3 links.

Which one of them open a iframe using fancybox. Is it possible create a NavArrows between the iframes like the Redmine do it?

Below the code

```
<!-- FancyBox -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<!-- FancyBox -->

<h2>fancybox v3.5 - Iframe</h2>

<p>
  Basic usage of fancyBox - simply add <code>data-fancybox</code> and <code>data-type="iframe"</code> attributes to your link.
</p>

<hr class="my-5" />

<p>

  <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="https://codepen.io/about/" href="javascript:;">
    Example #1 - Webpage
  </a>

  <br />

  <a href="https://codepen.io/pro/teams/" data-fancybox data-options='{"type" : "iframe", "iframe" : {"preload" : false, "css" : {"width" : "600px"}}}'>
    Example #2 - Webpage, custom options
  </a>

  <br />

  <a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html" href="javascript:;">
     Example #3 - Sample PDF file
  </a>

</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See docs - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage

> use the same attribute `data-fancybox` value for each of them to create
>   a gallery

So, replace `data-fancybox` with something like `data-fancybox="iframe"` and the gallery will be created from matching elements.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrKRRO?editors=1000

Comment: Works! Thank you!